# Why do we have to reverse the string when converting from infix to prefix

Tags: stack, prefix, evaluation, infix-notation

In the first step itself of converting an infix to prefix can someone explain in simple terms why should we reverse the string? Is there any alternative method to convert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are absolutely right that if you have to convert infix to prefix then you have to scan the string from right to left.

**Why not from left to right?**

If you scan from left to right then you will require future knowledge of operators in the string.

Example 1 :

```
Infix  : 2+3
Prefix : +23
```

Now, when you convert it from left to right then you should have the knowledge of + that is yet to appear in the string. This looks simple in this particular example, now consider another example given below.

Example 2:

```
Infix  : 2+3*4/5-6*7
Prefix : -+2/*345*67
```

Now, if you scan from left to right then when you scan 0th index of string then the program should have knowledge of - which is going to appear in 7th index of string which could be a hectic job.

So the safest way to do is to scan the string from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

**In the first step itself of converting an infix to prefix can someone explain in simple terms why should we reverse the string?**

Without stating which algorithm you're referring to you leave us to guessing, but a simple guess would be:

1. Read the Prefix expression in reverse order (from right to left)
2. If the symbol is an operand, then push it onto the Stack. Otherwise if the symbol is an operator, then pop two operands from the Stack and create a string by concatenating the two operands and the operator between them: string = (operand1 + operator + operand2)
3. And push the resultant string back to Stack
4. Repeat the above steps until the end of Prefix expression.
5. At the end stack will have only 1 string i.e resultant string

Note that in step 2 operand1 is the first to be popped.

Obviously why you can't read the string left-to-right is rather obvious in this algorithm: the first you'd read is an operator and you wouldn't have any operands to pop.

The algorithm works because it's kind of transforms it to postfix and uses the algorithm for converting postfix to infix. "Kind of" because in reversing you don't only put the operator after the operand, you also reverse the order of the operands (which is why in step 2 you consider the top operand to be the left operand).

**Is there any alternative method to convert?**

Yes, as the above algorithm is basically to abstractly evaluate a postfix expression and express it as infix. You can do the same thing directly with a prefix expression.

1. Output an open parenthesis
2. Read the first token, if it's an operand output it and we're done. Otherwise:
3. Convert input prefix expression (recursively using this algorithm)
4. Output token read in 2
5. Convert input prefix expression (recursively using this algorithm)
6. Output an close parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately most of the resources online suggest to do infix to prefix conversion by first reversing the infix string, then converting it to postfix and reversing the postfix again.

However, it is possible to convert infix to prefix directly by reading the infix from left to right and using two stacks.

Here is the pseudocode:

```
start reading infix from left to right

if scannedElement is '('
    push scannedElement to operator stack

else if scannedElement is ')'
    while (operatorStack peek is not equal to "(")
            operator is equal to operator stack pop
            firstPopOperand is equal to operand stack pop
            secondPopOperand is equal to operand stack pop
            formedOperation = operator + secondPopOperand + firstPopOperand
            push formedOperation to operandStack
    pop from operator stack (this will be "(")

else if scannedElement is an operator
    if operatorStack is empty or operatorStack peek's precedence smaller than scannedElement precedence
        operatorStack.push scannedElement
    else
        while (operatorStack is not empty 
        and operatorStack peek's precedence bigger than or equal to scannedElement precedence)
            operator is equal to operator stack pop
            firstPopOperand is equal to operand stack pop
            secondPopOperand is equal to operand stack pop
            formedOperation = operator + secondPopOperand + firstPopOperand
            push formedOperation to operandStack
        push scannedElement to the operator stack

if scannedElement is an operand
   push the scannedElement to operandStack

after the infix string scanned
while (operatorStack is not empty)
        operator is equal to operator stack pop
        firstPopOperand is equal to operand stack pop
        secondPopOperand is equal to operand stack pop
        formedOperation = operator + secondPopOperand + firstPopOperand
        push formedOperation to operandStack

result is equal to operandStack peek
```