# Regex/parantheses and comma separation in Python - ast.literal?

Tags: python, regex, split, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to split a string into a list, taking into consideration the following rules:

- Three elements per list (operator, element 1 and element 2)
- () at the start and end of the string, and used for nesting
- Separation of element by commas

Example:
A+B is encoded as '('+', 'A', 'B')

I can also have nesting, such as:

(A+B)-C encoded as '('-', ('+', 'A', 'B'), 'C')

I have been trying to use regex, but I didn't find what I want yet. I know how to deal with the nesting once I'm able to make the first split (in the example above, getting ('-', 'A+B', 'C'), but the real problem is how to start. I've been trying to read about regex but I'm finding it hard to understand and I've been unsuccessful.

EDIT: Wasn't sure if my goal was clear, my goal is to have a list of elements. In case of nesting, I need a list inside a list. My goal isn't to get A+B=C, but to get, as different elements in a list, '+', 'A' and 'B', in the same order they are in the sentence. In case of nesting, I should have a list within a list, with exactly the same appearance as the string but organized as different elements.

EDIT2: After some more search, I think what I need is something close to ast.literal_eval, but I'm not sure. The sentence to import is in correct Python list syntax, I just need Python to import it as such.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a parsing problem and cannot be solved with regexes (or only regexes).

Comment: Check infix to prefix algorithm to solve it.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23942225/infix-to-prefix-conversion

Comment: [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) is quite for this purpose.

Comment: PLY is a neat parsing module for Python. The following PLY example is related to your problem: http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/example.html